# Infer type member through pattern matching in Scala

Tags: scala

Is there a way to make it work? I.e. to tell the compile that within a patmat case the `e` has more specific type and so the static value of `Param`?

```
sealed trait MyEnum {
 type Param
}

object MyEnum {
  case object Value1 extends MyEnum {
    type Param = Int
  }
}

trait MyTypeClass[T]

val i: MyTypeClass[Int] = null

def get(e: MyEnum): MyTypeClass[e.Param] = e match {
    case MyEnum.Value1 => i
}
```

Currently the compiler fails with

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Playground.MyTypeClass[Int]
 required: Playground.MyTypeClass[e.Param]
```

Im working with scala 2.13.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a type parameter for the `get` method instead of directly matching `e.Param`. Modify the method like this:

```scala
def get[T](e: MyEnum { type Param = T }): MyTypeClass[T] = e match {
    case MyEnum.Value1 => i.asInstanceOf[MyTypeClass[T]]
}
```

This way, the compiler knows that within each case, `e.Param` is specific.

Comment: `asInstanceOf` is exactly the thing I'm trying to avoid. Casting shouldn't be required here. 

@Edit: I think it might work anyway without casting. At least scastie is not complaining. Will try to verify. Thanks.

Comment: It does work! I originally had more convoluted example that breaks a bit but the general solution is correct. Thanks again. 

The more convoluted case: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/oIR6v1wFT76Y11Os4uLJwA